# Convert object into a custom object

Tags: custom, object, process, conversion

we parted our workflow into 4 different objects on salesforce.
These are:

1. Lead
2. Opportunity
3. Deal
4. Exit

Each of these objects includes different phases and I would like to create a new record in the deal object when the opportunity record is marked signed.

My idea is, that a window shows up directly after the opportunity is marked signed and the user can enter important information that is needed in the deal object.

Right now, I tried to work with an automated process, but it only allows to copy existing information.
Unfortunately, I have no experience with apex.

Is it possible to reproduce the conversion assistant like in the conversion of a lead to an opportunity?

Many thanks!
Yannik

Comment: Did you try to do it using lightning flow?

Comment: I tried it right now and it works. My only problem is right now, how i can start the flow automatically after the opportunity is set to signed.

In the process builder its not possible to start flows which include windows.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can start this process using a Quick action.
You can save the time, to mark the opportunity as marked using this quick action and then starting the flow, that's how I would do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What do you mean with start this process using a quick action?

Comment: Instead of mark an opp as signed and then click on the quick action to open the flow. you can directly use the flow to mark an opp using the flow.
So the process will be like this --> you have a quick action named "Mark as signed" or sth like this, when you click on it, the flow will mark the opp as signed and then open the screens.

Comment: I achieved it. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: welcome! mark my comment as the answer.